# Play Framework Ebean always returns a null list in One to Many Relationship

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I'm using play 2.2.2, and I´m having problems with lists in One to Many Relatioships..

I have this current setup

```
@Entity
public class BD_Uno extends Model {
    @Id
    public int serial;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bd_uno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<BD_DOS> bd_dos = new ArrayList<BD_DOS>();

    public static Finder<Integer,BD_Uno> find = new Finder<Integer,BD_Uno>(Integer.class, BD_Uno.class);
}
```

and also:

```
@Entity
public class BD_DOS extends Model {

  @Id
  public int serial;

  @ManyToOne
  public BD_Uno bd_uno;

}
```

The current problem is that when I want to get the list of the One to Many Relationship, it always seems to be null:

```
    BD_Uno uno= new BD_Uno();
    BD_DOS dos = new BD_DOS();
    dos.serial = 2;
    dos.save();

    BD_DOS dos_dos =  new BD_DOS();
    dos_dos.serial = 3;
    dos_dos.save();     

    uno.serial = 1;
    uno.bd_dos.add(dos);
    uno.bd_dos.add(dos_dos);

    uno.save();

    BD_Uno test = BD_Uno.find.byId(1);
```

In this case when I see test.bd_dos it is always null!
What I´m doing wrong, I guess is something pretty stupid but is giving me a headache!

Thanks for the time,
Claudio

Comment: Save `dos` and `dos_dos` objects before adding them to collection.

Comment: That was fast!, thanks for pointing that out (I edit the code to reflect it) but it seems I´m with the same problem. Or at least when I inspect the 'test' object I see the 'list' field as null, maybe I´m doing something wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't initialize `bd_dos` here:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bd_uno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<BD_DOS> bd_dos = new ArrayList<BD_DOS>();
```

Instead, you can try the following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bd_uno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<BD_DOS> bd_dos;

...

BD_Uno uno= new BD_Uno();
uno.serial = 1;    
uno.bd_dos = new ArrayList<BD_DOS>();

BD_DOS dos = new BD_DOS();
dos.serial = 2;
// relate dos back to bd_uno  
// this should be optional since Ebean does this on its own  
dos.bd_uno = uno;

BD_DOS dos_dos =  new BD_DOS();
dos_dos.serial = 3;
dos_dos.bd_uno = uno;

uno.bd_dos.add(dos);
uno.bd_dos.add(dos_dos);

uno.save();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but sorry to say I have the same problem. Maybe I´m not been clear enough... In this case, the list under `uno` is fine (the ArrayList) but the one I get from the `find.by()` (`test`), is set as an EBeanList with a `list = null`

Comment: So when you save, you have a new record in your BD_UNO table but none in your BD_DOS table? What is the schema of your BD_DOS table?

Comment: I did some play clean´s and it seems to work now, thanks for the tips.